# How to calculate sum in th:each thymeleaf?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a list of persons that I need to display, and for each person there is an input for age.

I need to sum the ages when im writing; I mean if I have 5 persons when I'm on the 5th record, i need the total of previous 4 ages  like this one : [Calculate sum from number type input fields by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59133114/calculate-sum-from-number-type-input-fields-by-javascript)

this is my code :

```
  <tr th:each="person : ${persons}">
            <td th:text="${person.first_name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.last_name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${person.phone}"></td>
            <td><input id="age" class="form-control"
                        type="text" name="age" th:field="*{ages}">
            </td>
    </tr>

Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>
```

I did this js script, but in total it gives me only the value of first line !!!! Any help ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#age").each(function() {

            $(this).on('input', function(){
              calculateSum();
            });
            
            log.console("sum :"+sum);
          });

        });

        function calculateSum() {

          var sum = 0;
          $("#age").each(function() {
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
              sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

          });
          $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Use Thymeleaf's [aggregates](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#aggregates) function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add values in Thymeleaf variable in the loop and after complete loop display final value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556302/how-to-add-values-in-thymeleaf-variable-in-the-loop-and-after-complete-loop-disp)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59133114/calculate-sum-from-number-type-input-fields-by-javascript that answer my queston but i dont know how to adapt the code for my case, static table to table with th;each

Answer (score 0):

1. put all of the ages in array
2. On every place you want to show the sum of the previous ages:

2.1. slice the array from 0 to the place of the current value (beacuse slice(0,x) actually slicing the array from 0 to x-1).

2.2 execute the reduce function on the sliced array, you can see an example here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp

Comment: I added a script on JS but that dosent help "u cant see my edit on post "